# How to open a pointer with fopen?

Tags: c, fopen

Usually we open file in this way

```
FILE *student_file;

student_file = fopen("five_students", "rb");
```

Now I have a function with an image pointer as argument. I want to open the image file and read the content inside. I tried to open it as following, but it doesn't work. How can I fix it?

```
void read_metadata(FILE *image, int *pixel_array_offset, int *width, int *height) {
     FILE* img = fopen(*image, "rb");
}
```

Comment: Whats an image pointer? You don't need to `fopen` if you got a `FILE*`.

Comment: Ah, it is already a `FILE`. So I can read it directly?

Comment: Yep - Bingo! And it is good practice -- as you have done -- to open the file in the caller and validate it is open, before passing it to your function for reading. (although we don't see your validation check `if (student_file == NULL) { /* handle error */ }` then call `read_metadata`)

Comment: Yea, it's strongly recommended to check validation. Now I just try to open it first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already have the parameter `image` opened when you call `read_metadata` (i.e. if an earlier call to `fopen` succeeded in the calling code), you don't need to call `fopen` on it again. It is already open.  Also, that code shouldn't even be compiling, since `fopen` takes a `char *` string as its first argument, not a `FILE`.

Just use the file I/O functions on `image` right off the bat (`fread`, `fgets`, `fscanf`, etc.).